# Find a basis $Q$ of a linear transformation with respect to the basis $U$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: U \to U$ be a linear transformation and Let $U$ be a vector space over a field $F$ such that $U = \mathbb{C}^3$ and $F = \mathbb{C}$, the field of complex numbers. let $P = \{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ be the standard basis of $U$ and suppose that

$$T(e_1) = 8e_1 + 9e_3,\ \ \ \ T(e_2) = 3e_2, \ \ \ \ T(e_3) = -4e_1-4e_3$$

You are given that there is a basis $Q = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ of $U$ with respect to which $T$ has the matrix
$$B =\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Find such as basis Q.

I am quite lost on this problem. Am I correct in saying that we are trying to find what $v$ equals with respect to $e$? so $v_1 = e_2$? I am not sure if this is correct or where I could go after this even if it was correct.

Comment: You are looking for $S $ such that $T = SBS^{-1} $.

Comment: @bloomers could you elaborate a little bit? how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Can you tell by looking at B (which is upper-triangular and given as similar to T) what the eigenvalues of T must be?

Comment: @bloomers The eigenvalues would be 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes!  Now can you say anything further looking at B about whether each corresponding eigenvector will be genuine or generalized?

Comment: @bloomers Would 3 be genuine and 2 be generalized?

Comment: 3 is genuine, one 2 is genuine, and one 2 is generalized.  Now, can you express T in matrix form?

Comment: @bloomers Wouldn't $T$ just be the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 8 & 0 & -4\\ 0 & 3 & 0\\ 9 & 0 & -4 \end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: That's correct.  Now, I claim that $v_{1},v_{2} $ that are genuine eigenvectors for T corresponding to 3 and 2, and $v_{3} $, a generalized for 2, will provide such a basis $Q $.  Once you find these three, you can check that they do by forming $S $ with those vectors as columns, and confirming that $T = SBS^{-1} $.

Comment: @bloomers, Okay thanks, I think I understand it now.

Comment: That's great!  And you're welcome!